# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Vec2D'

Tags: python-2.7

I face a problem below.When I run another function related to this 'if',type error is "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Vec2D' ",then I cut off the int(),and the type error changes to "slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method ",wtf,waiting for someone's brilliant help.

```
def singleOrder(argument):
global position
global direction
if argument==']':
    lastPosition=position[len(position)-1]
    lastDirection=direction[len(direction)-1]
    turtle.setposition(lastPosition)
    turtle.setheading(lastDirection)
    position=position[:int(lastPosition)]
    direction=direction[:int(lastDirection)]
```

Comment: You *do* know that we have absolutely no idea what `argument`, `position`, or `direction` contain, right?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the last element of a list is easy:

```
del L[-1]
```